# Refresh(clear and refill) listview onTextChanged

Tags: android, json, listview

Code:

```
public class TopicsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


List<String> topics;
Map<String, Topic> topicsMap;
ListView listView;
EditText search;
String searchString;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] topicsArray;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

private static String url_topics = "http://192.168.2.102/discussion/get_topics.php";


// restaurants JSONArray
JSONArray Jtopics = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_topics);

    topics = new ArrayList<String>();
    topicsMap = new HashMap<String, Topic>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.topicsList);
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchTopic);
    search.addTextChangedListener(searchWatcher);

}

private final TextWatcher searchWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        searchString = "";
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        searchString = search.getText().toString();
        new LoadTopics().execute();
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};


class LoadTopics extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TopicsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading topics. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("searchString", searchString));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_topics, "GET", params);

        Log.d("All Topics: ", json.toString());


        try {

            int success = json.getInt("success");

            if (success == 1) {

                Jtopics = json.getJSONArray("topics");

                for (int i = 0; i < Jtopics.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Jtopics.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = c.getString("title");
                    String details = c.getString("details");
                    String date = c.getString("date");
                    String username = c.getString("username");

                    Topic t = new Topic(title, details, date, username);

                    topics.add(t.getTitle());

                    topicsMap.put(t.getTitle(), t);

                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                topicsArray = new String[topics.size()];
                topics.toArray(topicsArray);

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, topicsArray) {

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                        textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

                        return view;
                    }
                };

                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.topicsList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            }
        });

    }

}
```

In my code I have a TextWatcher. Every time I type in text in the EditText I want the list view to refresh/update/ clear and refill. The purpose of this is to search for topics as the user rights keywords in the EditText. The code as it is will retrieve the correct topics but for each letter input in the EditText the list will fill yet again with the same topics, so I will have duplicates and then triplicates and so on. I have tried `listview.setAdapter(null)` , I have tried clearing the adapter in the OnTextChanged method with `adapter.clear()` . I have also tried `topics.clear()` and then `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` . I know there are already questions similar to mine but they don't seem to resolve my problem. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried AutoCompleteTextView. This will help you in achieving required functionality.

Comment: But even if it provides suggestions, I still need to retrieve them right? So will they not be retrieved more than once if the user keeps typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a baseadapter class and implement filterable. Then in that class create a private filter class which extends Filter. And in your code create an adapter with that base adapter class and use adapter.getFilter().filter(newText) in your on text changed method.

Comment: I didn't create a baseadapter class . I just put `listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);` in my postexecute and used `adapter.getFilter().filter(searchString)` in my on text changed method like you suggested and it works. Thanks :)